# strace reports x32 and 64 bit mode

Tags: strace

I am confused about this strace report on an ArchLinux, 64bit intel machine:

```
~ sudo strace -c -p 876
[sudo] password for pmatos: 
strace: Process 876 attached
strace: [ Process PID=876 runs in x32 mode. ]
strace: [ Process PID=876 runs in 64 bit mode. ]
```

Why does it say that the process runs in *both* x32 and 64bit mode? I assume `x32` means `32 bit mode`.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

strace have a handful of heuristics to try to detect the mode of the binary (32bit, 64 bit, x32 and so on).

This logic is not accurate in all cases, so you're seeing a result of that. 
(This is also the consensus on the [linux kernel mailing list](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1604.0/05086.html))